# Correct the [lithum-ion] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[lithum-ion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lithum-ion) is misspelled.  Currently, five questions are tagged with this misspelled tag.

I propose two solutions:

---

### Option 1: Burninate [lithum-ion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lithum-ion).

Just use the more general [battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery).  Are different battery technologies too localized?

---

### Option 2: Add tags for different battery technologies.

On the other hand, it might be useful to make tags like

- [li-ion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/li-ion)
- [nimh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nimh)
- [nicd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nicd)

After some browsing, I've seen multiple questions in which the question or answer is ambiguous because the battery chemistry isn't clear.  (*Lithium ion*'s needs are different from *nickel-metal hydride*'s.)

Examples:

- [https://superuser.com/q/248065](https://superuser.com/q/248065/83694)
- [https://superuser.com/a/197891](https://superuser.com/a/197891/83694)
- [https://superuser.com/q/377650](https://superuser.com/q/377650/83694)
- [https://superuser.com/a/55937](https://superuser.com/a/55937/83694)
- [https://superuser.com/a/203197](https://superuser.com/a/203197/83694) (Contrary to this answer, a Google search for "`nimh laptop battery`" found that NiMH laptop batteries do exist.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updating post history, 7 rows affected
updating posts, 5 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [lithium-ion] and [lithum-ion] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym lithum-ion -> lithium-ion was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Comment: Do we really need the synonym?

Comment: @DanielBeck dubiously, but if somebody's mistyped it before, it's not inconceivable that they might mistype it again. Granted, unlikely with the tag suggestions, but the better questions, "does it hurt?"